# Having Trouble with aligning a Hamburger Menu and Two Images in one header

Tags: html, css, image, header, hamburger-menu

I am working on creating what I thought was a simple header!

I have my hamburger menu on the far left, one image right next to the hamburger, on the far right side one more image and a header bottom border.

[Here is an image of what I am trying to create:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SibgT.jpg)

I am having a very difficult time getting all three images on one line with a space in between the two images. I want the three to be scalable so that if it is viewed on a smaller screen they don't just stack up on top of each other. I also want them to be even and vertically centered.

A bonus fix would be if someone knew how to create the layered look of my far right image with the border showing underneath, but this is not my priority at the moment.

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 70px;
transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 0.8;
}

.sidenav a {
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
color: #000000;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #E1E0E1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 25px;
font-size: 36px;
margin-left: 50px;
padding-top:40px;
}

.openbtn {
background-color: #fffff;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 0;
height: 55px;
}

.openbtn a:active{
color: #ffffff;
}

header {
border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E0E1;
overflow:auto;
margin-left: 35px;
margin-right: 35px;
height: 90px;

}

h1 {
margin-top: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
margin-right: 0;
}

h1, h2, .openbtn {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 540px) {
h1 {width: 100%;}
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
.sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
.sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="#">- three</a> <br> <br>
<a href="#">- two</a> <br> <br>
<a href="#">- three</a> <br> <br>
<a href="#">- four</a> <br> <br>
<a href="#">- fivr</a> <br> <br>
</div>

<div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" class="openbtn" 
onclick="openNav()"> 

<img src="hamburger.png"/> </div>

<h1> <img src="lch1.png"/> </h1>

<h2> <img src="lolo1.png"/> </h2>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` at wrapper. it is a great property which help us to align all its child in centet with respect to each other.

You can check sample at the following link

```
https://codepen.io/jainaman23/pen/NgWEVW
```

Comment: This worked really well and making my images into .svg files made them scalable. When I scale down to mobile size the images are scaling and staying on the same line but are kind of overlapping each other, especially the hamburger menu and the first image. Do you know how to keep them line up exactly in the same line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the hamburger and first image float property to left. and then set the float of the last picture to right. That would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: inline-block`
So your pictures will be in ohne line and you can them as `Display: block` elements